# is there an azure policy to check diagnostic settings of a function app sends logs to log analytic workspace

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-function-app, azure-diagnostics, azure-policy

The following blocks in policy rule doesn't match with arm template..
Azure policy to ensure that function app logs are sent to log analytics workspace via diagnostic settings.

```
{
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
            "exists": "false"
          }
```

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: @JimXu sure.. I have edited

Comment: Sorry I also cannot understand the issue. Is that you want to create a policy to check if the function has enabled diagnostic settings. If not, deploy it. Right/

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, the [Azure Policy definition structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-rule) is different from the ARM template syntax in a few ways.

There isn't a policy already available that performs the exact ask, but there are some [built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/samples/policy-reference) for Azure Monitor that you can reference and **customize** in order to satisfy your requirement:

- [Audit diagnostic setting](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F7f89b1eb-583c-429a-8828-af049802c1d9): Audit diagnostic setting for any of the selected resource types ([Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Monitoring/DiagnosticSettingsForTypes_Audit.json)).

  Note that for `AuditIfNotExists` effect in the policy, for new and updated resources, Azure Policy adds a `Microsoft.Authorization/policies/audit/action` operation to the activity log and only marks the resource as non-compliant.
- [Deploy Diagnostic Settings to Log Analytics workspace](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2Fc84e5349-db6d-4769-805e-e14037dab9b5): Deploys the diagnostic settings for Batch Account to stream to a regional Log Analytics workspace ([Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Monitoring/Batch_DeployDiagnosticLog_Deploy_LogAnalytics.json)). This policy has the `DeployIfNotExists` effect on resources.
- [This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/App%20Service/AppServiceFunctionApp_AuditHTTP_Audit.json#L25-L41) is another simple policy that demonstrates working with Azure Functions.